# Jinja2 reuse set vars as filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I ask you for help to solve my filter problem on Jinja2.

my_vars.yaml

```
nodes:  
  - name: m01
    port: 7001
    bus_port: 17001
  - name: m02
    port: 7002
    bus_port: 17002
  - name: m03
    port: 7003
    bus_port: 17003
  - name: s01
    port: 7011
    bus_port: 17011
    replicaof: m01
  - name: s02
    port: 7012
    bus_port: 17012
    replicaof: m02
  - name: s03
    port: 7013
    bus_port: 17013
    replicaof: m03
```

example.conf.j2

```
{% if nodes.name|first in 's' %}
{% set n = nodes.replicaof %}
{{ n }}
{% endif %}
```

result: m01

I would like to reuse the 'm01' to retrieve the port and the name and possibly other information when I loop on the service 's01'

When I work on node **s01**.
I would like to find who is master and collect the information from node **m01**.

Working Node :

```
- name: s01 
  port: 7011 
  bus_port: 17011 
  replicaof: m01
```

expected result:

```
m01 7001
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could look like this:

Playbook (`main.yaml`):

```yaml
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    nodes1:
      - name: m01
        port: 7001
        bus_port: 17001
      - name: m02
        port: 7002
        bus_port: 17002
      - name: m03
        port: 7003
        bus_port: 17003
      - name: s01
        port: 7011
        bus_port: 17011
        replicaof: m01
      - name: s02
        port: 7012
        bus_port: 17012
        replicaof: m02
      - name: s03
        port: 7013
        bus_port: 17013
        replicaof: m03

    nodes2:
      m01:
        port: 7001
        bus_port: 17001
      m02:
        port: 7002
        bus_port: 17002
      m03:
        port: 7003
        bus_port: 17003
      s01:
        port: 7011
        bus_port: 17011
        replicaof: m01
      s02:
        port: 7012
        bus_port: 17012
        replicaof: m02
      s03:
        port: 7013
        bus_port: 17013
        replicaof: m03
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: example1.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/example1.conf
      when: >
        nodes1 | selectattr('name', 'equalto', inventory_hostname) | map(attribute='replicaof') | first is defined
      tags: case1

    - template:
        src: example2.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/example2.conf
      when: >
        inventory_hostname in nodes2 and
        'replicaof' in nodes2[inventory_hostname]
      tags: case2
```

Template for the `case1` (`templates/example1.conf.j2`):

```
{% set replica = nodes1 | selectattr('name', 'equalto', inventory_hostname) | map(attribute='replicaof') | first %}
{% set node = nodes1 | selectattr('name', 'equalto', replica) | first %}
{{ replica }} {{ node.port }}
```

Template for the `case2` (`templates/example2.conf.j2`):

```
{% set replica = nodes2[inventory_hostname].replicaof %}
{{ replica }} {{ nodes2[replica].port }}
```

Exacution:

```sh
ansible-playbook -i s01, --diff -t case1 main.yaml
ansible-playbook -i m01, --diff -t case1 main.yaml
ansible-playbook -i s01, --diff -t case2 main.yaml
ansible-playbook -i m01, --diff -t case2 main.yaml
```

I would personally prefer the `case2` solution as it results in much simpler implementation but it requires to change the original data structure.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks, but I think I misspoke.

When I work on node S01, I would like to find who is master and collect the information from node M01.
Working Node :
      - name: s01
        port: 7011
        bus_port: 17011
        replicaof: m01

expected result:
m01 7001

Comment: @unLucKy please do not spread the necessary info to answer your question over volatile comments. [Edit your question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66324462/edit)

Comment: @unLucKy I have fixed the solution. Please have a look.